# Solution of a diophantine linear equation system

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

I want to find out for what triples $(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{Z}^3 $ the following system  of linear diophantine equations has a solution:

$$\begin{cases}
24x+\phantom{1}6z=a, \\
24x+16y=b, \\
32x+\phantom{1}8z=c.
\end{cases}$$

I can find solutions by trying numbers, but cannot figure out how to obtain a general solution.

Comment: $$\{(a,b,c)\in\mathbb Z^3:a=24x+6z,b=24x+16y,c=32x+8z, (x,y,z)\in\mathbb Z^3\}$$ or $$(a,b,c)=x(24, 24, 32)+y(0,16,0)+z(6,0,8).$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By computing [Smith Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form), we get$\newcommand\bmat[1]{\begin{bmatrix}#1\end{bmatrix}}$
$$\bmat{2&0&0\\0&8&0\\0&0&0}\bmat{3&0&4\\0&1&0\\1&0&1}=\bmat{0&0&1\\1&-1&-4\\-2&3&8}\bmat{24&24&32\\0&16&0\\6&0&8}.$$
Then the image of the homomorphism
\begin{align}
&\Bbb Z^3\to\Bbb Z^3&
&[x,y,z]\mapsto\bmat{x,y,z}\bmat{24&24&32\\0&16&0\\6&0&8}
\end{align}
is given by
$$\bmat{a,b,c}=\bmat{x,y,z}\bmat{2&0&0\\0&8&0\\0&0&0}\bmat{3&0&4\\0&1&0\\1&0&1}=\bmat{6x,8y,8x}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Put $a=6A,b=8B,c=8C$. Then we have $4x+z=A=C$, $3x+2y=B$. Now take any $x$ st $B-3x$ is even (ie take $x$ odd if $B$ is odd, and even if $B$ is even. Then we have $z=A-4x,y=(B-3x)/2$.

So the requirements on $a,b,c$ are:

we have $a=6A, c=8A$ for some integer $A$; $b$ can be any multiple of 8.

Comment: $b=24x+16y$ and $b$ can be any integer ???

Comment: @YvesDaoust Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly $6|a, a=6A$(say) $A=4x+z$

$B=3x+2y$

$C=4x+z$

$z=4x-C$

$3x+2y=(3-2)B\iff3(x-B)=-2(y+B)$

$\dfrac{2(y+B)}3=-(x+B)$ which is an integer

$\implies3|2(y+B)\iff3|(y+B), y+B=3D$(say) $\iff y=3D-B$

$-(x+B)=2D$  where $A,B,C,D$ are arbitrary integers